# How to make rspec load config.ru?

Tags: rspec

I am using the `rack-contrib` gem to set the locale from the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header, so my `config.ru` file has

```
puts 'Running config.ru'
require 'rack'
require 'rack/contrib/locale'
use  Rack::Locale
```

When running in development mode I see the message `Running config.ru` but when I run rspec, I do not see the message, so rspec is not loading config.ru.

In development mode the locale is set by `Rack::Locale` as expected. When I run this test file, `rspec spec/requests/localization_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe 'Localization' do
    describe 'Setting from header' do
        it 'should set the locale for french' do
            header 'ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 'fr'
            gets '/'
            expect(last_request.env['rack.locale']).to eq 'fr'
        end
    end
end
```

the locale is not set to `:fr` and I do not see the `Running config.ru` mesage.

Comment: can you share your test?  likely rspec doesn't load your config.ru so it doesn't know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSpec doesn't load `config.ru` as it doesn't know what it is. You need to simulate what a web server would do. This approximates it for a rack test style setup. Including `Rack::Test::API` into your specs would allow you to use rack-test with a rackup file.

```
module Rack::Test::API
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    @app ||= Rack::Builder.parse_file('path/to/config.ru').first
  end
end
```